# Flexible space above and below an environment

Tags: margins, environment-variables

I have used the `amsthm` package to define a new environment as follows:

```
\newtheoremstyle{examplestyle} % name of the style
  {10pt} % space above
  {10pt} % space below
  {\normalfont} % font of body
  {} % space to indent
  {\slshape} % head font
  {: }% punctuation between head and body
  { } % space after head
  {} % manual head
```

It works well, however, I would like if the environment is positioned at the top or bottom of pages, the space above/below to be `0pt` (not `10pt` as defined). I know this can be achieved manually by inserting `\hspace{-10pt}` each time the environment happens to touch the bounderies of the page, however, is there an automatic way LaTex to do this?

PS I am used to declare by hand where pages break with `\newpage`, so there is a way LaTex to know exactly where pages begin/end...

Comment: Providing a minimum working example demonstrating the issue would be very helpful for those willing to help you.

Comment: the spaces you describe are supposed to disappear automatically at the top or bottom of a page.  if they don't, then something is wrong.  with an example demonstrating the problem, this will be tested, and if really a bug, will be added to the ams list.  (a number of problems have been reported with `amsthm`, but this isn't one of them ... yet.)

Comment: Thank you for the remark - you are right. The spaces are working as they are supposed... I was confused to think the opposite, since `vspace{-10pt}` indeed usually reduces the space between an *example* (at the bottom of the page) and the page number, however this has worked only if the `10pt` could be "consumed" by elongating the spaces around *equations* (or other sorts of flexible environments) at the same page. Please, excuse me for this confusion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is apparently the result of a misunderstanding, as noted in the comments